# C#/Unity - Returning the retrieved string from a UnityWebRequest coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, return, global-variables, coroutine

How can I return the 'data' variable from the coroutine to a variable in the validate subroutine? I've attempted normal returning, making it a global variable, callbacks, I can't seem to make it work....... some help would be greatly appreciated

[PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vlzq.png)
[image]

Comment: Please provide code as text. We can't debug an image, screen readers can't read an image, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since coroutines / web requests run asynchronously, you can't get a return value from them normally (because the rest of the program does not stop until they are done, so by the time there is a return value your program can be anywhere in your code). You can have them update some shared variable and then check every frame in Update() whether they are done or not, and use that share variable when done.

But the better and cleaner way to get variables from coroutines is using [callbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-implement-callback-functions). That means you pass a paramater to the coroutine which is a method that you want to run with the result, and the coroutine will call that method as soon as it is complete.

See this example on how to use a callback with a web request coroutine:

```
    private void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(DoWebRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com", ParseWebResult));
    }

    private void ParseWebResult(string resultText) {
        Debug.Log("Result of web request: " + resultText);
    }

    private IEnumerator DoWebRequest(string url, System.Action<string> callback) {
        using (UnityWebRequest wr = UnityWebRequest.Get(url)) {
            // Request and wait for the desired page.
            yield return wr.SendWebRequest();

            isWrDone = true;
            if (wr.isNetworkError) {
                Debug.LogError("Error getting www data: " + wr.error);
            } else {
                callback(wr.downloadHandler.text);
            }
        }
    }
```

In this example you pass two parameters to the coroutine - the URL and a method that will handle the result. Then in `Start()` I start this coroutine, and pass it a url as a parameter, and also pass it the `ParseWebResult()` method that will handle the result.

The `ParseWebResult` method receives a string (the result of the web request) and prints it to the log. This is where your own code should go to handle the result properly.

You could also use inline lambda instead of defining a separate message to handle the result:

```
    private void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(DoWebRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com", (string result) => {
            Debug.Log("Result of web request: " + resultText);
        }));
    }
```

In this example I use the lambda syntax to define the WWW handler inline. You can [read more about the lambda here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions).